# Display other field onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have here selectbox with option value USA and OTHERS. What I need is if I choose OTHERS on Selectbox1 the Selectbox2 should be display none and textbox1 comes out. Other problem also is it's name field, If I POST the value of `name="cboState"` . How to remove the name of a field? Any help will appreciate.

```
<form action="try.php" method="POST">
<select id="cboCountry">
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="OTHERS">OTHERS</option>
</select>
```

**Selectbox 2**

```
<select id="cboState" name="cboState">
    <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
</select>
```

**Textbox 1**

```
<input type="text" id="cboState" name="cboState"/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<select id="cboCountry">
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="OTHERS">OTHERS</option>
</select>

<select id="cboState" name="cboState">
    <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="txtcboState" name="cboState" style="display:none;"/>
```

JS

```
$("#cboCountry").change(function() { 

    if ( $(this).val() == "OTHERS") {

    $("#cboState").hide();

    $("#txtcboState").show();

}
    else{

        $("#cboState").show();
        $("#txtcboState").hide();
    }

});
```

Note: **`ID` Must be unique for each element.**

To remove The `name` attribute of `input`, you can use the following

```
$("#txtcboState").removeAttr('name');
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/RPJLS/)**

Comment: It works. But the problems is the remove name doesn't working

Comment: If I choose to select on dropdownlist, the POST value is empty bcoz it get the value of textbox instead of dropdown value

Comment: when do you want to remove the attribute??

Comment: how do you take the value for `post`??

Comment: I add form, then I POST it on other page through the field name

Comment: The problem with this is textbox1 and selectbox 2 has a same name.

Comment: get the post value through id of a field?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$("#selectbox1").onchange(function() { selectionChanged();});

function selectionChanged() {

if ( $("#selectbox1").val() == "other") {

    $("#selectbox2").hide();

    $("#textBox1").show();//should already be hidden

}

}
```

Make sure the IDs for your elements are unique.

Comment: jquery does not have a method called  `onchange` please correct your code