# How to add/change fields dynamicaly in form from if else condition?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here i have numerous input fields in a form, which are working perfectly. And now, i want to add new input boxes and their labels according to `property_type` , Which is already exist on this page.

Now, Kindly Suggest me How can i add new fields in that form.

**Here is my Form Code**

```
     <div class="dashboard_price_left">

    <h3>
        <?php
        if ($this->lang->line('BasePrice') != '') {
            echo stripslashes($this->lang->line('BasePrice'));
        } else
            echo "Base Price";

        ?>
    </h3>

    <p>
        <?php
        if ($this->lang->line('Atitleandsummary') != '') {
            echo stripslashes($this->lang->line('Atitleandsummary'));
        } else
            echo "Set weekly or monthly price guests will see for your listing.";

        ?>
    </p>

</div>
<?php
if ($listDetail->row()->home_type == 'Office') {

} else if ($listDetail->row()->home_type == 'House') {

}

?>
<form id="pricelist" name="pricelist" action="site/product/savePriceList" method="post">
    <div class="dashboard_price_right">

        <label><?php
            if ($this->lang->line('Pernight') != '') {
                echo stripslashes($this->lang->line('Pernight'));
            } else
                echo "Per night";

            ?>
        </label>

        <div class="amoutnt-container">
            <?php if ($currentCurrency == '') { ?>
                <span class="WebRupee"><?php echo $currencyDetail->row()->currency_symbols; ?></span>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <span class="WebRupee"><?php echo $currentCurrency; ?></span>
            <?php } ?>
            <input type="text" id="price" value="<?php
            if ($listDetail->row()->price != '0.00') {
                echo intval($listDetail->row()->price);
            }

            ?>" class="per_amount_scroll"  name="price" onkeypress="return onlyNumbersWithDot(event);" onchange="javascript:Detailview(this,<?php echo $listDetail->row()->id; ?>, 'price');" />
            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $listDetail->row()->id; ?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="dashboard_currency">
            <label><?php
                if ($this->lang->line('Currency') != '') {
                    echo stripslashes($this->lang->line('Currency'));
                } else
                    echo "Currency";

                ?>
            </label>
            <div class="select select-large select-block">
                <select name="currency" id="currency" onchange="javascript:Detailview(this,<?php echo $listDetail->row()->id; ?>, 'currency');get_currency_symbol(this)" >
                    <!--<option value="">select</option>-->

                    <?php foreach ($currencyDetail->result() as $currency) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $currency->currency_type; ?>" <?php if ($listDetail->row()->currency == $currency->currency_type) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $currency->currency_type; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Here is a pic of my Property prices form**

[image]

**Note:** There are two types of property that are following:

**1. Office**

**2. House**

on the basis of these property, I want to add more fields in my form.

Please suggest me, Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Have you thought about using javascript to display new fields are selected?  Quite a few examples of this around. This is one of a million http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283613/display-other-field-onchange

Comment: nope, i just want to use simple PHP if else mechanism.

Comment: you can check for all fields which belongs to property type or you can use two different form on you condition.

Comment: can you show me example which field you wanto to change base on property type

Comment: if my property type is "Office" then want to add 'per day', 'half day' and 'per hour' ,, And if my property type is "House" then i want to add 'per night', 'per day' and 'per hour'.

Comment: If you want to use a php only solution you need to submit the form back to the server and rebuild the form based on the property type selected. If you dont want to refresh the page then you need to look at a JS solution

Comment: JS is already exist their, i just want to put input boxes with their names according to property type in that form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change it  base on conditon and pass hidden field which indicates you office or house.

```
<?php
if ($listDetail->row()->home_type == 'Office') 
{
<input type="hidden" name="home_type" value="Office" />
<input type="text" name="per_day" value="" />
<input type="text" name="half_day" value="" />
<input type="text" name="per_hour" value="" />
} 
else if ($listDetail->row()->home_type == 'House') 
{
<input type="hidden" name="home_type" value="House" />
<input type="text" name="per_night" value="" />
<input type="text" name="per_day" value="" />
<input type="text" name="per_hour" value="" />
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, But can you suggest me where i can put your code within my code? just above(Outside) of form?

Comment: @AshishVyas in form tag

Comment: Thanks Buddy, Its Done